# Is there a way to delete all the edited messages before the one you delete?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In my bot, I edited the same message around 3 times. In the end, when I wanted to delete the last one, I thought it would delete all. But it just deleted the last edited message.

Is there any way to do it? Because I tried to use several delete_message, but it kept on the last edited message...

## Example of the execution

`1. "First Message"
2. "Second Message" (edited)
3. "Third Message" (edited)
4. "Forth Message" (edited)`

## Expected

`No messages`

## Actual Result

`"Third Message"`

Comment: How are you editing the message? So you are editing the same messages several times, delete it then and then Telegram uses the second edit? Are you sure? Could you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could *just* delete all the messages that were `edited`:

Perhaps a starter:

```
test_list = ['1. First Message', '2. Second Message (edited)', 
             '3. Third Message (edited)', '4. Forth Message (edited)', 
             '5. Fifth Message (edited)']


for t in test_list[:]:
    print(t)
    if 'edited' in t:
        test_list.remove(t)    
print(test_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['1. First Message']
```

one-liner using lambda:

```
print(list(filter(lambda a: a != '(edited)', test_list[:])))
```

Comment: @AndréOliveira obviously, should have posted a snippet otherwise. Like I said, a starter to give an idea. Maybe you could add a marker to each `edited`  message and delete all those with the marker